# making a chat client and wont work

Tags: python, sockets

what's wrong here I'm stuck :(
I'm using **3.4.4** if that helps
I've tried everything! I've even searched on this! It keeps saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matthew\Desktop\chatclient.py", line 36, in <module>
    s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": " + message.encode(), server)
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Here's the code:

```
import socket
import _thread
import threading
import time

tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False

def recieving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
                tLock.acquire()
                while True:
                    data.addr = sock.recvfrom(1024).decode() 
                    print (str(data)) 
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 0

server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)

rT = threading.Thread(target=recieving, args=("recvthread", s))
rT.start()

alias = input("Name: ")
message = input(alias + "-> ")
while message != 'q':
    if message != '':
        s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": " + message.encode(), server)   
    tLock.acquire()
    message = input(alias + "-> ")
    tLock.release()
    time.sleep(0.2)

shutdown = True
rT.join()
s.close()
```

could it be my server I will type it if needed!
and thx again!

Comment: `s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": " + message.encode(), server)` like the error message says you are trying to add `": "` to things that you already encoded to byes. The fix, make a str of `alias + ": " + message` and then `encode` that at all at once

Comment: thx ill try that now!

Answer (score 0):

The message is right! Once you encode `alias` and `message`, they are `bytes` not strings. But `": "` is a string, hence the error. In python 3.x, strings are unicode and need to be encoded to bytes to be saved to disk or sent on the wire.

An additional but subtle error is that you are using the default encoding for your computer but really the sending and receiving computers should agree on an encoding and use that. UTF-8 is a good choice.

So, change

```
s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": " + message.encode(), server)
```

to

```
s.sendto("{}: {}".format(alias, message).encode('utf-8'), server)
```

Comment: hi how can I check it work's I don't have another pc :(

Comment: and do I have to do something to my server as well?

Comment: The server side should `decode('utf-8')`. You can run the both on the same machine. If `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is already 'utf-8', it will be hard to spot places where you are still using the default encoding.

Comment: quitting = False
print ("Server has started!")

while not quitting:
    try :
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024).decode('utf-8') 
            if "Quit" in str(data):
                quitting = True
            if addr not in clients:
                clients.append(addr)

            print (time.ctime(time.time()) + str(addr) + ": :" + str(data)) 
            for client in clients:
                s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), client.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: I'm not sure.. except that you want `client` not `client.encode('utf-8')`. The target IPv4 address should not be encoded, just the data.

Comment: thx for your help but I'm gonna have to restart do you know any tuts?

Comment: google shows some chat server examples but I don't know them personally. Good luck!